Function prop passed to component is undefined in Vue3
I've got a problem where I want a child component to call a function given to it as a prop from the parent. I have done it before with other components, but with this it just doesn't work.
Here are the relevant parts of my parent component:
<template>
  <DataTable
    :on-double-click="goToDevicePage"
  />
</template>

And here are the relevant parts of my child component:
<template>
  <TableRow
    v-for="(row, index) in filteredRows"
    :key="row.id"
    @dblclick="() => handleDoubleClick(row)"
  />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  onDoubleClick?: (cells: any[]) => void;
}>();

function handleDoubleClick(row: any) {
  const cells = row.getVisibleCells();
  if (props.onDoubleClick !== undefined) {
    props.onDoubleClick(cells);
    console.log("onDoubleClick is defined and called with cells:", cells);
  } else {
    console.log("onDoubleClick is undefined");
  }
}
</script>

This always logs that the function is undefined and I'm not sure why.
I have tried making the function in the parent component to an arrow function like so:
:on-double-click="(cells: any[]) => goToDevicePage(cells)"

I have also tried things like setting the prop to required in the child component and typescript gives me no error, but it still logs that its undefined and if I remove the check, it just throws an error. I also tried some things like adding .prop to the parent component prop and removing the 'on' in the name of the prop because chatgpt said vue may be thinking it's an event listener, but literally nothing works.

please recreate the problem on https://play.vuejs.org

funnily enough, in this vue workspace it works, but not in my code. i have triple checked it and it's basically the same thing except that my components are around 300 lines instead of 20. (the link is too long to send)

This is what https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is about , it needs to contain enough code to reproduce the problem. And if it's specific to your setup (I'm unaware of the conditions that could make it possible in your case) then the setup too. It needs to be reproducible from scratch

The issue you're encountering is because Vue interprets any prop name starting with "on" as an event listener, which Vue treats differently than a standard prop. When you name your prop onDoubleClick, Vue assumes it's an event listener and does not pass it as a regular prop, which is why it appears undefined in the child component.
Solution
To avoid this issue, rename the prop to something that doesn't start with "on" (e.g., doubleClickHandler or handleDoubleClick). Here’s how you can modify your code:
Parent Component
<template>
 <DataTable
  :double-click-handler="goToDevicePage"
   />
</template>

Child Component
<template>
  <DataTable
  :double-click-handler="goToDevicePage"
   />
</template>

Explanation
Renamed Prop: Changing onDoubleClick to doubleClickHandler prevents Vue from interpreting it as an event listener. Vue will now pass it as a standard prop.
Access the Prop Normally: In the child component, you can now use props.doubleClickHandler as expected without Vue interfering.
Additional Tips
If you need a naming convention for props that trigger actions, using names like onDoubleClickCallback or handleDoubleClick can also help avoid issues.
This should fix the problem, and you’ll see your callback function defined in the child component as expected!

I thought I had tried this approach so I didn't bother trying again. But coming again to this project I decided to try again your idea and it worked. Thanks for the help!

The problem is that, in Vue, property names are automatically camelCased, so :on-double-click in the parent component is passed as onDoubleClick to the child. In Vue's template syntax, though, on- prefixed properties are treated as event listeners, not as regular properties, hence it's not passed down to the child component as you've expected.
To fix this, change the following in the parent component: Change :on-double-click="goToDevicePage" to :onDoubleClick="goToDevicePage", in order to avoid the event-listener interpretation. By renaming on-double-click to onDoubleClick in the parent, Vue will pass it as a standard property instead of treating it as an event.
